# php mysql match value from multiple values a column

Tags: php, mysqli

I want to find a value from a column which has multiple values like (23,24,25), Using php mysqli query.

Table:

```
+-----------------+
id | tag_ids  |
+-----------------+
1  | 3,4,5    |
2  | 3,7,8,9  |
3  | 4,5,10   |
```

Curent query:

```
$value = '3';
$query = "SELECT tag_ids FROM table WHERE FIND_IN_SET($value, tag_ids)";
$result = mysqli_query($query);
$count = mysqli_num_rows($result);
echo count;
```

Result will be: YES/NO or 1/0, if the Given value is match any value with tag_ids.

Comment: What Have You Tried So Far? Where Is Your **Tried** Code?

Comment: @NanaPartykar tried query added

Comment: So, What's Happening With Your Code. It's Written Correct. What Problem Are You Facing?

Comment: What is the data type of the `tag_ids` column? Is it a `SET`?

Comment: @NanaPartykar i just getting value 0 always

Comment: Database connection variable is missed in mysqli function.

Comment: @NanaPartykar i know that and i made example here, db connection is not problem

Comment: @JiriHrazdil varchar ?

Comment: Oh... do not ever use varchar to save multiple values into a single column. It is better to change the structure of your table so that you use 10 rows to save your data (`id`, `tag_id`): (1, 3), (1, 4), (1, 5), (2, 3), (2, 7), (2, 8), (2, 9), (3, 4), (3, 5), (3, 10). With that structure you can query like: SELECT `id` FROM `table` WHERE `tag_id` = 3

Comment: Yes. Database Normalization Is One Important Concept Which You Should Take Care Of. Nevertheless, Your Code Is Working In My System.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the result my self and here is code:

```
function statusvalues() {
    $query = "SELECT tag_ids FROM tblname WHERE tag_ids !=''";
    $result = mysqli_query($query, DBCONN);
    $idarray = array();
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
            array_push($idarray, $row['tag_ids']);
    }

    return $idarray;
}

function status($ID) { //Passing tag id

    $set_of_numbers = statusvalues();
    $reset_numbers = implode(", ", $set_of_numbers);
    $values =  explode(", ", $reset_numbers);

    if (in_array($ID, $values)){
        return "disabled";
    }
}
```